# printer_list for PHP 7.3.4

Tags: php, xampp

I am using `PHP Version 7.3.4` and `XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.3`. Now i want to show all installed Printers from our Print Server. But i didn't found the newest Version of `php_printer.dll`

i already included a extention and wrote it into the php.ini

```
<?php
$printers = printer_list ( PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL );
print_r($printers);
?>
```

Am i just using a wrong PHP Version? Cause pages like these: https://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-list.php are unavailable.

Comment: My Error is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function printer_list()

Comment: Im not sure but i thought the dll defines it. Sorry but im very new in Programming in General.                                                                                                                  Do i need something like array printer_list ( int $enumtype [, string $name [, int $level ]] )

Comment: https://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-list.php link was expired and also for your php version defiantly not available  `printer_list` function. Check [MIke42](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php)